# "shotgun" command prompt Ruby - "No such file or directory - uname (Errno::ENOENT)"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rackup, shotgun

I've installed Ruby onto my Windows PC and have a home.erb file with a route that is described in my app.rb file.

My Gemfile currently looks like:

```
#Gemfile
source :rubygems

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sass'
gem 'rake'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'pry'
gem 'require_all'

group :test do 
gem 'rspec'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'rack-test'
end
```

I've been running the "bundle install" command on the 'Start Command Prompt With Ruby'. I've successfully installed the 'sinatra', 'shotgun', 'rake' (etc.) gems onto the Ruby application.

However, every time I run "shotgun" to see my website in progress, I get the following error in the terminal.

```
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:102:in ``': No such file or directory - uname (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:102:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:101:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:101:in `find'
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:101:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby24/bin/shotgun:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby24/bin/shotgun:23:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile is under Ruby24/lib/personalsite.

Any help would be appreciated as I am just starting off with website development! Thanks!!

Comment: `uname` is a Unix shell command/program. I take it from your error message that this is Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Shotgun does not work on Windows. From the [Shotgun docs](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun#compatibility):

> **Compatibility**
>
> Because of the underlying technique used, Shotgun is only compatible with systems that support fork(2) (probably just MRI on POSIX systems).

If you're running Windows 10 and feeling adventurous, I would suggest [trying out the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/). This way you can run a POSIX compliant subsystem on Windows, and use tools such as Shotgun without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Shotgun doesn't work on Windows, but [`rerun`](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) runs fine on my Windows 7 machine.